# Overwrite element in list

Tags: python

I'm creating a function that returns the time. I wanted it to display am/pm instead of having a max of 24h. So I needed to first substract 6 on the hour if it is above 12.

But nothing is happening, I'm not even getting an error and I have no idea what is the cause for this. Can someone explain what is the cause?

```py
import datetime

MONTHS = 'jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec'.upper().split(' ')
def get_date():
    # 01-OCT-1978 04:31:17
    
    date = datetime.datetime.today().__str__().split(' ')
    date[0] = date[0].split('-')
    
    if int(date[1].split(':')[0]) > 12:
        date[1].split(':')[0] = str(int(date[1].split(':')[0]) - 12)
        
    real_date = date[0][2] + '-' + MONTHS[int(date[0][1])] + '-' + date[0][0] + ' ' + date[1].split('.')[0]
                
    return real_date

print(get_date())
# 07-APR-2021 21:56:12
```

Comment: You are using `datetime.datetime.today()` which doesn't have a time part. I believe you want to be using `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Comment: Additionally to what pavel already noted, you probably don't want to manipulate the string representation of the date & time (which, additionally, you should probably acquire by calling `str` instead of the core corresponding magic method). Instead, in this case, you actually want to format it differently, and for that https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime exists.

Comment: Since you asked why your solution doesn't work: `split` returns a *new* list that doesn't change when the `str` changes (even if it was mutable), and that also doesn't change the `str` if it changes. Instead, you would have to get the list, change it, and `join` it back together to get the new string with the changed contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is fundamentally based on the issue that methods like `split` return a *new* piece of data, that was generated out of its inputs, but is not linked to it anymore after it is returned; in this line of your code:

```py
date[1].split(':')[0] = str(int(date[1].split(':')[0]) - 12)
```

To give some easier examples:

```py
s = "a:b:c"
l = s.split(":")  # this returns a *new* list `["a", "b", "c"]`
s += ":d"  # `l` is still `["a", "b", "c"]`, even though `s` is now `"a:b:c:d"`
l[0] = "e"  # `s` is still `"a:b:c:d"`, even though `l` was changed to `["e", "b", "c"]`
```

You can, however, overwrite the old data with the function that undoes `split` - `join` / redo the operation when the original data changes:

```py
s = "a:b:c"
l = s.split(":")  # Note that this is won't actually do anything since it's going to be overwritten two lines down
s += ":d"  # `s` is now `"a:b:c:d"`
l = s.split(":")  # `l` is now `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`
l[0] = "e"  # `s` is still unchanged...
s = ":".join(l)  # but can be updated from the changed `l`, such that it will now be `e:b:c:d`
```

Note that them not being linked makes more sense when you consider functions that actually lose information when applied - such as `len`:

```py
s = "abc"
len(s) = 4  # Note that this is not valid syntax; but if it were, what should `s` now be?
```

---

As was noted by others, the best solution to this would be to replace this with [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime), as this does the job more easily, more concisely, it's easier to read and it's the "proper" way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

For your problem, I would suggest a whole new solution that better utilize the powerful `datetime` module.

```py
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")

print(date)
# '2021-03-08 10:54 AM'
```

The reason your code doesn't work is that you are editing a temporary variable that is not stored. You have to create a variable to store the split list, and then concatenate them back.

If you change the middle part to

```py
t = date[1].split(':')
if int(t[0]) > 12:
    t[0] = str(int(t[0]) - 12)
date[1] = ':'.join(t)
```

which will work. But I have to remind you, this way will create further complexity in appending `'AM'` and `'PM'`, while using the module will be much convenient.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend splitting each value into variables. Using lots of list indexes and methods is fine, but it is much more readable by using variables instead of many list indexes.

```py
str_datetime = datetime.datetime.today().__str__().split(' ')
(year, month, day), (h, m, s) = (str_datetime[0].split('-'), str_datetime[1].split(':'))
if int(h) > 12:
    h = str(int(h) - 12)
    ampm = "PM"
else:
    ampm = "AM"
date = f"{day}-{MONTHS[int(month)]}-{year} {h}:{m}:{round(float(s))} {ampm}"
```

This would give the following value of `date`:

`'07-APR-2021 7:08:59 PM'`

However, instead of using such lengthy methods, you can just use the `datetime.datetime.strftime()` method. For example:

```py
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

This gives the following output:

```py
'07-Mar-2021 18:56:37 PM'
```

For reference, here is a list of [`datetime.datetime.strftime` format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: This works fine, but I would like to know why my way isn't functional.